# How to select form inside div with span as criteria?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to get value from form elements inside div area. The form is selected when the div having span element with class name 'custom radio checked'

```
<div class="row pascabayar-regis-number">
       <div class="columns twelve mobile-four">
               <input type="radio" name="pick_number" value="62817306603">
    <span class="custom radio checked"></span>
       </div>
</div>
```

How i can do that using jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i am not wrong you want `radio` button having `span` inside of same `div`.

Use `.has().`

```
$('.columns:has("span.checked")').find('input:radio');
```

Comment: @bijakas2...its not selecting it..?? have you checked in firebug.?

Comment: thanks for the hint , i modified code : $('#columns:has("span.checked")>input[name="pick_number"]').val();